# Visualization of Black holes

Tags: black-holes, visualization

I have generally seen pictures of black holes like these

[image: Blackhole 1]
[image: Blackhole 2]

I have also read in a lot of places that black holes can't be seen and we have predicted the locations of black holes because of its gravitational influence.

Which one is correct? or is it that both of these exist under different circumstances?

If both of these is wrong, then what exactly is the correct theory?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.01290

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a black hole is just sitting with nothing around it, you won't be able to see it.  It emits Hawking radiation, which is important from a theoretical perspective, but is such a tiny amount that we can't see it.

If a black hole comes near a cloud of gas or collides with a star, though, it will pull some of that matter inside its event horizon, but lots will stay outside in its accretion disk.  This gas heats up as it's brought near the black hole, and when it gets hot it emits light that we can see.  The really really big instances of these at galactic centers are [quasars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar), which are some of the brightest objects out there.

The actual event horizon of a black hole is usually pretty small (a black hole with the mass of the Sun would only have a radius of 3km and the event horizon of Sagittarius A*, the black hole at the center of the Milky Way, is only 7 million miles, which is only 8% of the distance between the Sun and the Earth), so they're difficult to image well.  We only managed to get the first image that could see an event horizon two years ago with the [Event Horizon Telescope](https://eventhorizontelescope.org) which used many telescopes from many countries to effectively have a radar dish as big as the Earth—their website has details about how and why they did this.  It's a pretty insane achievement.

But anyways, if we were very close to a black hole (or if EHT was much much better), we might see something pretty similar to those pictures!  They are just artists' impressions that may miss some of the physics (for instance, those ones don't have [jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_jet) which black holes often do), but they are paying attention to detail, like how you can see the stripy bands of light at the top of the black hole in the left image, each of which comes from light that was bent around the black hole a different number of times.

Comment: That explained stuff pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Black holes can be seen, but to see one you have to be fairly close or use very powerful magnification from a distance.

The event horizon surrounding the black hole itself appears black. The glowing disk that you see around the event horizon in these visualisations is the [accretion disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk) of matter falling into the black hole.

Until recently, we had never seen a real black hole directly, and evidence for their existence was indirect, based on their gravitational effects such as [gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave), [gravitational lensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens) and their effect on the motions of other stars. However, in 2021, the [Event Horizon Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_Telescope) (which is actually a global array of radio telescopes rather than a single instrument) produced an image of the supermassive black hole at the centre of the [M87 galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messier_87).