# Visualization of Shape of Black Hole

Tags: black-holes, visualization

I had asked [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/800337/visualization-of-black-holes) question a couple hours ago and I got some pretty good answers which cleared up my doubts. but it led to even more doubts.

Why exactly is the hot gases accumulated in particular shapes? Is it just the visualization?
[image: Blackhole 1]

By that logic, the entire surface of the Black Hole should be covered with hot gases and not just rings. Even the picture of Sagittarius A captured by the Event Horizon Telescope reveals patches of hot gases instead of it covering the entire surface.

Why would this be the case?

[image: Sagittarius]

Comment: Some keywords for you to google: the stuff falling into the black hole takes the shape a ring called the accretion disk. The weird shape in the top picture is due to gravitational lensing - it's not the actual shape of the disk, the light is distorted by gravity.

Comment: I saw a talk once that said that that one of the lumps in the EHT picture is a jet that's in the direction of the camera.  It may have been one of their other images and I'm sorry I don't have a better source, but the point is there's lots going on.

Comment: Don't know, but it looks like the same reason why (some) galaxies are flat and planets orbit a star, more or less, *in a plane*. Must have something to do with the interaction of matter and where it comes from.

Comment: Thanks. Will do some more research myself and make a self answer if I get something interesting